# GoogleMap with a lot of different places and restricted zoom

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have to put a Map from Google (Google Maps or GoogleMyMaps) in a website. I need the map to show a lot of different places all over my country (about 200 places). I already have a GoogleMyMaps with all the places.

But I need the map to have a **zoom limitation/restriction** : I want people ***NOT TO KNOW*** exactly where the places are, which means the zoom must stop *before it gets accurate enough*.

I know you can control the zoom with *GoogleMaps JS API* with something like

```
 var opt = { minZoom: 6, maxZoom: 9 };
 map.setOptions(opt);
```

But I dont know how to add places on a Google Maps (still I have them all on a Google**My**Maps).

Thank you for your time

Comment: Did you try Google Maps markers:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple 
?

Comment: Is it possible to have several markers on a single map ? I guess I could make an array of places, but isn't 200 places a lot ?

Comment: You can display your "MyMap" data on a Google Maps Javascript API map.

Comment: As far as I know you can add as many markers as you want. Once it starts to work slowly, you should investigate about marker clusterers:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your help.

So most of the time, GoogleMyMaps uses .KML files (as import or export), and it is possible to upload the data from a .KML file into Google Maps.

Here is an example :

```
<script>
    function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 6,
            center: {lat: 1, lng: 1}
        });

        var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
            url: 'THE_KML_FILE_URL',
            suppressInfoWindows: true,
            map: map
        });

        kmlLayer.addListener('click', function(kmlEvent) {
            var text = kmlEvent.featureData.description;
            showInContentWindow(text);
        });

        function showInContentWindow(text) {
            var sidediv = document.getElementById('content-window');
            sidediv.innerHTML = text;
        }
    }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY_HERE&callback=initMap"
async defer></script>
```

But note that the KML file has to be online, it does not work on local (Google's API needs to have access to your file).

Then you can customize your Google Map using Google Map Javascript API (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial).

Thank you everyone for your time